# java stream with 2 filters conditions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to Filter with 2 conditions a `List` using a `Stream`:

```
private List<String> filterResources(final List<Resource> resources, final String resourceType, final String propertyName) {
    List<String> result = resources.stream()
            .filter(resource -> resource.isResourceType(resourceType))
            .map(Resource::getValueMap)
            .map(valueMap -> valueMap.get(propertyName, StringUtils.EMPTY))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result.stream().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'd like not to create the result object, thanks in advance.

Comment: Then don't collect it. Rather do the filtering logic before doing the collect part.

Comment: did you mean `List<String> result = resources.stream()
                .filter(resource -> resource.isResourceType(resourceType))
                .map(Resource::getValueMap)
                .map(valueMap -> valueMap.get(propertyName, StringUtils.EMPTY))
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Btw you don’t need to make the method parameters “final”.

Comment: out of curiosity what made you think you have to collect the result into a list then filter ?

Comment: The first question that came into my mind was “Is `StringUtils.EMPTY` the same as `""`?”, so congratulation, you’ve just used a named constant that makes the code *less* understandable than code just using the value…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason for two `Stream` pipelines. You can apply the second filter on the original `Stream` pipeline before the terminal operation:

```
private List<String> filterResources(final List<Resource> resources, final String resourceType, final String propertyName) {
    return resources.stream()
            .filter(resource -> resource.isResourceType(resourceType))
            .map(Resource::getValueMap)
            .map(valueMap -> valueMap.get(propertyName, StringUtils.EMPTY))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Or better `.map(valueMap -> valueMap.get(propertyName, String.class)) .filter(Objects::nonNull)`, which doesn’t map absent values to an empty string and won’t confuse them with actual empty string values…